# Convert issue of jsonDate into Angular application

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework

I have create my application using Entity framework & Angularjs & Mvc 5

when i will bind data of Company in table using ng-repeat.found date in this format /Date(1420137000000)/.

How we can convert it in date format.

at time of edit records same date fromat is showing in ng-model control

how can convert it in date format ??

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Do you need to format the date in your view or in your controller? Please share some of the code you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the **[`date format filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)** ,

```
{{1420137000000 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}
```